# How to change window decorations in GTK theme

Tags: gtk, theme, window-decorations

I recently came across the Equilux theme [here](https://github.com/ddnexus/equilux-theme). I really like it but I wanted OSX window decorations, so I started copying assets from this [OSX-arc](https://github.com/LinxGem33/OSX-Arc-Darker) theme to the Equilux theme. I have so far succeeded in copying the window decoration assets from the xfwm4, unity and metacity-1 folder and it seems to work.

However in apps that use CSD window decorations like pamac and most gnome apps it still shows the original Equilux window decoration. I can't find any window decoration assets in any other folders other than unity, metacity-1 and xfwm4. I have replaced all of these and removed the old decorations but it still shows the original. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Gnome Tweak Tool? You can install the package via command line.

https://itsfoss.com/install-switch-themes-gnome-shell/

Oomox is also a very handy theme tool 

https://github.com/actionless/oomox

Comment: What I mean is actually changing the CSS code and assets of the theme. Oomox doesn't support this.

Comment: Gotcha, best of luck. it has been a while since I have edited gnome apps' CSS but iirc it is spread throughout different files. good luck.